# ssh connection to ec2 instance without password

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, ubuntu, amazon-ec2, ssh

I need a help, I was setting up a keyboard-interactive, close the server session, and now I can not enter? I have my key `(.pem)` to enter, but now it asks for a password and the server does not have a password, I use the key to enter

Comment: Have you imported public key file in IAM ? You need to start ec2 instance with public key. How do you create new instances ?

Comment: @GillesQuenot I have the public key (.pem) to start session in ssh, but now it does not leave me because it asks me too (Authentications that can continue: keyboard-interactive)

Comment: .pem IS NOT PUBLIC it's the PRIVATE KEY

Comment: @GillesQuenot sorry, yes Private key, I have private key, but still ask (keyboard-interactive)

Comment: Basically the problem is that it is incorrectly configured ((keyboard-interactive)) and that's why it asks me for a password and it does not work, but I should just let it enter with the private key and it does not.

Answer (score 1):

What I have done when I had the same problem ([aws](/questions/tagged/aws) says it's key pair, but in fact you just have *private key* when you generate a 'key pair' in aws console):

- download the private ssh key `*.pem` on your computer
- generate the pubkey : `ssh-keygen -y -f aws.pem  > aws.pub` (replace `aws` by the name of your key)
- ***import*** the public key (`*.pub`) in [ec2](/questions/tagged/ec2) *key pairs*
- create a new instance and ***associate key pair*** (depends how you create instance, I can tell you for [terraform](/questions/tagged/terraform))
- now you can ssh to your [ec2](/questions/tagged/ec2) instance `ssh -i aws.pem user@host`

### Note

I think the first step is not required, you can just generate key pair on your PC with `ssh-keygen`, then import the `public key` in [ec2](/questions/tagged/ec2) without the need of generating any keys from [aws](/questions/tagged/aws)

Comment: I can not just create another instance, because I can not lose what is in the current :(

Comment: Basically the problem is that it is incorrectly configured ((keyboard-interactive)) and that's why it asks me for a password and it does not work, but I should just let it enter with the private key and it does not.

Comment: How did you connect before to the instance ? Do you use [tag:ebs] ?

Comment: before with privatekey.. normal.. but I wanted to put a little more security by adding a (keyboard-interactive). and close the session unintentionally, now it asks me in addition to the private key ((keyboard-interactive).)

Comment: If you made changes, take a look to the snapshots to recover previous state

Comment: If you use [tag:ebs], you can try to mount the volume in another instance and modify what's wrong

Comment: Guide to attaching the a volume to another instance: https://n2ws.com/blog/how-to-guides/connect-aws-ebs-volume-another-instance